# what happens when declaring a method virtual and hide it in the derived class?

Tags: c#

```
  class A {
      public virtual void Foo()
           { // do something
            }
    }

  class B:A {
      public void Foo() {
       }
    }
```

What's the meaning of this? Can anyone give me an example? Up till now i thought that it's mandatory to use the "override" keyword if you use virtual
Thanks

Comment: I am sure you are getting warnings on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875580/why-do-we-use-virtual-and-override/7876032#7876032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use such declaration you will just "hide" the `Foo` method of the `A` class using instance of the `B` class. When you cast this instance to the `A` and call `Foo` the method of `A` class will be called.

If you will use `override` in the class `B` you will use `Foo` method of the `B` class if you create instance of the `B` and then cast to `A`.

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A Foo");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B Foo");
    }
}

B b = new B();
b.Foo(); // call 'B Foo'
A a = (A)b;
a.Foo(); // call 'A Foo'
```

With override:

```
B b = new B();
b.Foo(); // call 'B Foo'
A a = (A)b;
a.Foo(); // call 'B Foo'
```

For details you can Google a little. For example this post: [Polymorphism, Method Hiding and Overriding in C#](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword may bring you a better understanding. When you define a method in a class, it is `new` by default(if you didn't mark it with abstract/virtual/override/etc), which means this method has no business with those defined in the base class, no matter they have the same name.

```
 class A 
 {
     public virtual void Foo() { }
 }

 class B : A 
 {
     public new void Foo() { }
     public new void Bar() { }
     public void Baz() { }   //it's also new
 }
```

Now suppose we have `B b = new B();`. If you were asked which method would be invoked by `b.Bar()`, you will give the correct answer: the method Bar in class B. But you maybe confused if the question is about `b.Foo()`, just think it's new in B, don't care those methods in A. And so does `b.Baz()`.

**EDIT** Now here comes `A a = new B();`. What will happen if `a.Foo()`? Just think the `Foo` defined in B has no business with A, since a is defined as A, the method Foo in A is invoked.